# gerrit bypassing existing git server-side hooks

Tags: git, gerrit

I have git server-side hooks (update and post-receive) on a remote repo that I want gerrit to use. Gerrit documentation says that gerrit doesn't support the standard git server-side hooks and has their own hook plugin to do their own hooks. Does that mean I have to define an entirely new set of hooks or is it easy to delegate to the existing hooks? I'd like to avoid copy pasting a bunch of stuff that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Hooks plugin documentation following:

- [Configuration](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md)
- [Supported hooks](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md)